# Every clang command (including --version) results in Segmentation fault

Tags: clang, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-22.04

So I am doing a completely clean install with `sudo apt install clang`. Then when I try to verify installation with `clang --version`, I always get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. That's it, there are no other messages of any sort, and the same goes for every command.

I checked that prerequisites (build-essential, xz-utils, curl) and dependecies are indeed installed. I am using wsl. I haven't touched any environment variables. I also do have gcc installed (there never were any problems with it yet).

Have anyone else encountered this (or similar) problem? Any ideas why this might be happening?

(Edit:

`wsl -l -v` output: `* NAME: Ubuntu; STATE: Stopped; Version: 1`

`wsl --status` output: `Default Distribution: Ubuntu; Default Version: 1`

)

Comment: Can you add the output of `wsl.exe --version` and `wsl.exe. -l -v` to your post?  Any chance the distro is running on WSL1?

Comment: I did try this on Ubuntu 22.04 under both WSL1 and WSL2 and haven't been able to reproduce it (yet).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I am running my Ubuntu distro on WSL1. I will now edit the post to incude version info.

Comment: I think, that I will look if I really have something important on the subsystem itself. If no, I will just reinstall Ubuntu and install clang directly after.

Comment: Do you have the ability to run WSL2 on that system?  This looks suspiciously like a WSL1 issue, but I haven't yet found the link to my answer on the topic.

Comment: Just set version to WSL2, prompted `wsl update` and restarted WSL. Sadly, problem still persists. I will then try the above mentioned "reinstall WSL" option, but a bit later and now with initial clang installation on WSL2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Ubuntu distribution on WSL2 solved the problem, but why exactly had the problem appeared in the first place - no idea.